# Adjectives and ambiguity in meaning

Tags: meaning, adjectives, ambiguity

Read the following sentence:

> The lazy people of our family like this car.

Does the word "lazy" in the phrase "the lazy people of our house" only refer to the group of people that are lazy? Or does it refer to the all the people in the family and also call them lazy?

Comment: Please mind the punctuation.

Comment: Im sorry ; i just wanted to get the answer so i didn't give much attention to punctuation

Comment: It's ok, I already helped you edit it :) By the way, welcome to ELL!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"The lazy people of our family...."

1. First, it should be "the lazy people **in** our family..."
2. And it means only those people in our family who are lazy. It does **not** characterize everyone in the family as lazy.
3. If you want to characterize everyone in the family as lazy, you can say:

**Our lazy family** drives to get the mail at the end of the driveway.

or

**Everyone in our lazy family** owns a single-story house so they don't have to walk up the stairs.

Comment: Then how do I describe everyone as lazy

Comment: Not sure why I was downvoted, but I modified my answer to address your question.

Comment: It makes it really confusing if people over the same platform have different views on the same language

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically speaking, the cited usage is ***inherently ambiguous***. In practice it's incredibly unlikely the speaker is singling out just *some* of his family as "the lazy ones" (almost certainly he's characterising his *entire* family as lazy).

But if we just change ***lazy** [people]* to, say, ***younger** people* or ***female** [members]*, then suddenly that "specifically defining" sense (***only*** the young / female) becomes the most likely interpretation.

CONTEXT IS EVERYTHING

Comment: I totally disagree with the interpretation. I believe the speaker was talking about only a portion of the family. However, I agree with your assessment that context is everything.

Comment: Effectively, it's completely irrelevant that we disagree over what's the most "likely" interpretation of OP's text, because ***we have no context*** on which to base our judgements. But would you change your mind if we changed initial ***The*** to ***Those***, for example? I take it you agree that if we change ***lazy people*** to ***female members*** then unquestionably the most likely interpretation is ***only** the females* (and ***not*** the males). But even that is at least *potentially* ambiguous (if all (surviving) members of the family are female! :)

Comment: ***Men** aren't usually interested in making jam, but the **female** members of our local WI club find it fascinating*. Nothing wrong with that, even if we take it for granted that the WI club rules prevent "male members" from even existing! :)